# How to pass and use the parameters of JavaCV HoughCircles method

Tags: java, javacv, mat, hough-transform

I'm trying to use the JavaCV implementation of the [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) method, but I'm having some issues with the parameters.
Here is my code:

```
Mat currentImageGray = tgtFrag.getImage().clone();
Mat detectedCircles = new Mat();

HoughCircles(currentImageGray, detectedCircles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 2, 254, 25, tgtFrag.getImage().rows() / 4, 0 );

if (detectedCircles != null && !detectedCircles.empty()) {
    // TO DO:
    // Print the center and the raidus of the detected circles.
}
```

First of all, the results of the detection (second argment of the `HoughCircles`) are given as a Mat (`detectedCircles`).

I'd like to process the `detectedCircles` Mat and somehow print the center and the radius of the circle on the console. My attempts have failed so far: I've been trying to iterate `detectedCircles` using a `FloatBufferIndexer`, could be the right direction, but I didn't succeed yet, anyone can help?

Please notice the following:

- I'm using JavaCV, not openCV.
- I'm using JavaCV HoughCircles, not cvHoughCircles (a solution using cvHoughCircles would be also ok though).
- I'm using the latest version of JavaCV, i.e. 1.0 (July 2015).

Answer (score 1):

I've only been able to use the JavaCV cvHoughCircles method, no idea about how to use the HoughCircles method though. Here is my adaptation of your code.

```
// Get the source Mat.
Mat myImage = tgtFrag.getImage();
IplImage currentImageGray = new IplImage(myImage);
CvMemStorage mStorage = CvMemStorage.create();

CvSeq detectedCircles = cvHoughCircles(currentImageGray, mStorage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 2, 254, 25, tgtFrag.getImage().rows() / 4, 0);

if (detectedCircles != null && detectedCircles.total() > 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < detectedCircles.total(); i++) {
        CvPoint3D32f curCircle = new CvPoint3D32f(cvGetSeqElem(detectedCircles, i));

        int curRadius = Math.round(curCircle.z());
        Point curCenter = new Point(Math.round(curCircle.x()), Math.round(curCircle.y()));

        System.out.println(curCenter);
        System.out.println(curRadius);      
    }

}
```

Even though this does not directly solve your problem, I hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks @Tzeencth, this could indeed solve my problem, even tough I'd like to see the HoughCircle method used, rather than cvHoughCircles. I will wait some time before marking this as the answer to my question.